# How could I detect if there is an uppercase character in a string

Tags: javascript

I've read countless articles about people able to detect if all characters in a string are uppercase...

```js
function isUpperCase(str) {
    return str === str.toUpperCase();
}


isUpperCase("hello"); // false
isUpperCase("Hello"); // false
isUpperCase("HELLO"); // true
```

But I'm curious how I can take a string, and search to see if any characters are uppercase, and if so, return true or return a string with the characters that are uppercase.

Any help is massively appreciated, I'm trying to avoid posts on here but I couldn't find an answer that worked for me anywhere else.

Comment: Use a regular expression. `/[A-Z]/` will match an uppercase letter.

Comment: `/\p{Lu}/u` matches if the string contains any [uppercase letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) and will also support other languages than english.

Comment: @Barmar so you consider Ü to be non-uppercase?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the same logic you used for all uppercase, turn the string to lowercase and if its not equal to the original string it has an uppercase letter in it.

```js
function hasUpperCase(str) {
    return str !== str.toLowerCase();
}


console.log(hasUpperCase("hello")); // false
console.log(hasUpperCase("Hello")); // true
console.log(hasUpperCase("HELLO")); // true
```

Comment: I wish it was this easy, I keep getting errors that say that .toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: You must be calling the function with something that isn't a string. @DonnyyZ

Comment: @Musa A perfect and consice solution

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression to filter out and return uppercase characters. However, note that the naïve solution (as proposed by some of the other answers), `/[A-Z]/`, would detect only 26 uppercase Latin letters.

Here is a Unicode-aware regex solution:

```
const isAnyUpper = string => /\p{Lu}/u.test(string)

isAnyUpper('a') //    false
isAnyUpper('A') //    true
isAnyUpper('ф') //    false
isAnyUpper('á') //    false
isAnyUpper('Á') //    true
```

Comment: @CodyGray Your edit was misleading and unnecessary. This solution does not *"use a regular expression to filter out and return uppercase characters"*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the function is only taking string of ascii letters:

```
function isAllUpper(str) {
    return str.split('').findIndex(ch =>  {
      const code = ch.charCodeAt(0);
      return code >= 65 && code <= 90;
    }) === -1;
}
```

If you want to return just the string with only the uppercase letters, then you can extend the above slightly:

```
function onlyUpper(str) {
    return str.split('').filter(ch =>  {
      const code = ch.charCodeAt(0);
      return code >= 65 && code <= 90;
    }).join('');
}
```

Comment: The assumption of ASCII-only is unrealistic.

Answer (score -1):

It's as simple as:

```js
const hasUpperCase = str => /[A-Z]/.test(str);

console.log(hasUpperCase('abcd'));
console.log(hasUpperCase('abcD'));
```

*Limitation*: This only works for ASCII strings

Comment: It doesn't work for `Ü` and such.

Comment: Assuming that uppercase means A-Z is as wrong as using ASCII for storing arbitrary text. Here on Stack Overflow, I expect to read high-quality, general answers. Answers assuming that English is the only language in the world don't qualify for that.

Comment: The answer should mention its limitation, but otherwise this is a valid answer given some constraints. Not everyone needs an international solution.